# How to sum a range without sum()

Tags: python, function, built-in

Can anyone give me a tip on how to create my own sum function? I am not allowed 
to use sum()...

```
def add_divisors(start,stop,j):
    xs = (start,stop,j)
    for x in xs:
        #student code
        return sum(range(start,stop,j)) # How to sum without sum()
        #cannot use sum()
    #add_divisors(11, 11, 11) → 11 # 11 is a multiple of 11
```

Comment: Do you understand what `sum` does internally?

Comment: Furthermore I do not get what the `for` loop is doing here. The loop is executed *exactly* once, and does nothing with `x`. So you could have ommitted that.

Comment: If this is exactly your homework, I don't really want to write it for you... Maybe you could be a bit more specific about what part you are struggling with

Comment: It adds everything in the parenthesis..

Comment: @Anonymous: what I mean is, *how* does `sum` do that, not *what* the blackbox is doing.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy the only thing you have to think that functionality of sum as mentioned in comment.

**Check this:-**

```
def add_divisors(start,stop,step):

    ls = list(range(start,stop,step))
    total = 0
    for i in ls:
        total+=i
    return total

print(add_divisors(2,6,1))
```